# How can I duplicate a master branch as a develop branch and push it to gitlab without changes

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch

I just created a new repo in gitlab and I have a master brach and a feature branch (changes in the feature branch have already merged to master), I wanted to create a dev branch and push it to gitlab and make sure it looks exactly the same as my master branch, so I checkout from master branch and name it 'dev', but I can't really commit anything because there's no change in this dev branch, so I tried to push it directly, but it shows this (doesn't seem right):
[image]

I'm new to git, just wondering what is the best way to create this 'dev' branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
git push origin dev
```

This should create a dev branch in your remote repository.

Comment: It shows me an error: ```error: src refspec dev does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.git'```

Comment: Please do ```git status``` to see if you need to commit before pushing

Comment: it shows ```On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .idea/
        src/__pycache__/
        terraform/.terraform/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)```

Comment: Try ```git add -A``` then ```git commit -m "Merged master"``` then ```git push origin develop```

Comment: It works! Is it because there are conflicts in these system files between dev and master branch?

Comment: I glad it helped. No it was because you had some untracked files - just needed to go through that process. Please mark it as resolved :)

Comment: actually I just checked gitlab, the dev brach is still not here...When I run the last command, it says ```Enumerating objects: 26, done.
Counting objects: 100% (26/26), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 2MiB | 31.00 KiB/s```

Comment: I think that's something unrelated to the original question, but it might be because you're send something too large. Do you have large files in your project? Maybe a node_modules directory? You should have a .gitignore file in your project that ignores these large files and directories that you don't want to send to a remote repo.